# docs.python.org is different with the code

Tags: python

I'm a beginner in Python. I noticed the [DOC](https://docs.python.org/3/library/decimal.html?highlight=divmod#decimal.Context.divmod) said the function **decimal.getcontext().divmod(x,y)**  *returns the integer part of the result.*

But the code is:

```
def divmod(self, a, b):
    a = _convert_other(a, raiseit = True)
    r = a.__divmod__(b, context = self)
    if r is NotImplemented:
        raise TypeError("Unable to convert %s to Decimal" % b)
    else:
        return r
```

and the `a.__divmod__(b, context = self)` is（I just paste the end of the function）:

```
def __divmod__(self, other, context = None):
    #omit by me
    quotient, remainder = self._divide(other, context)
    remainder = remainder._fix(context)
    return quotient, remainder
```

Does that mean that the function returns a tuple includes quotient and remainder? If that is so, why the doc said '*returns the integer part of the result.*'

I tried to find that it did return to a tuple.

So, does the doc wrong?

Comment: The doc is wrong, yes. `divmod` does what [its builtin equivalent](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#divmod) does.

Comment: → https://docs.python.org/3/bugs.html

Comment: How to mark this answer as "accepted"?

Comment: You can't "accept" a comment.  If @L3viathan doesn't wish to create an answer to can create  an answer yourself, and accept it.  It's usual to [mark such answers as 'Community Wiki'](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251597/question-with-no-answers-but-issue-solved-in-the-comments-or-extended-in-chat), so that it doesn't look like you are trying to gain reputation from somebody else's contribution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In answer form:

The doc is just wrong. `divmod` does what [its builtin equivalent](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#divmod) does.